# Browser.AttachTo method in WatiN to support all browser's child window?

Tags: c#, watin

How to get latest trunk revision of WatiN.Core.dll to support "Browser.AttachTo" method? Or is there any other way to support "AttachTo" method (similar to AttachToIE for IE) for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I just released WatiN 2.0 RC 1 which includes this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is included, I've been looking for the same thing, but you can access the code link from this URL:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/develop

If you click the "Browse Code" link it will take you to the repository list, where you can either select the file you want and download it or download the GNU tarball.

I love Watin, but this is one I'm stuck on at the moment. My cross-browser tests are working well though!

Huge thanks to Jeroen Van Menen (sp?) for this amazing test framework!